# Host vs DnsSafeHost

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I need to get the host out of the Request object. Which property should I use and why?

From MSDN:

> **Uri.DnsSafeHost Property**
>
> A String that contains the unescaped
>   host part of the URI that is suitable
>   for DNS resolution; or the original
>   unescaped host string, if it is
>   already suitable for resolution.

vs

> **Uri.Host Property**
>
> A String that contains the host name.
>   This is usually the DNS host name or
>   IP address of the server.

My testing has been with the ASP.NET Development Server. Both of these always return `localhost`. Even when I put in 127.0.0.1, both return `localhost`.

Reading on, the `DnsSafeHost` property will handle IPv6 addresses, as well as Unicode to ASCII conversion if needed. It can also account for IRI and IDN. Even though I currently don't care about these things, should I just use the `DnsSafeHost` property to be safe?

Comment: `IdnHost` is now provided as the preferred alternative to using `DnsSafeHost`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.idnhost

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Apply *DnsSafeHost* to the URL if you intend to send the resulting host name to a DNS server on your own. DNS was originally an ASCII-only protocol ([and a subset of ASCII at that](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035#section-2.3.3)). Present day URL's allow character sequences in the host portion of a URL that cannot be sent directly to a DNS server. Examples are:

- [bracket-enclosed IPv6 addresses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6#Literal_IPv6_addresses_in_network_resource_identifiers). DnsSafeHost drops the brackets.
- Non-ASCII, non-English domain names. DnsSafeHost (optionally) uses [RFC 3987 IRI](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3987.txt) to normalize the characters, and converts non-ASCII character to [IDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name), [Punycode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode) encoding.
- Who knows what URLs will allow in the future? The application may well outlive our assumptions of what's okay in a URL. DnsSafeHost adds a degree of resilience there.

If you need to display the host name to the user, use the *Host* property instead.

Comment: That makes sense. I didn't think about how Host could be used the display name, and DnsSafeHost to be used programatically. Thank you for the clear and concise answer!